# How to select between two dates without using year to get birthday

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
select * from tbl_contact e where e.dob between to_date('26-APR-2000','DD-MON-YEAR') and to_date('03-MAY-2002','DD-MON-YEAR')
```

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: This is not a question, voting to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the type of dob field of your table is date,the following query will help you:

```
select * from tbl_contact e where e.dob between
                                                 to_date('26-APR','DD-MON')   and to_date('03-MAY','DD-MON')
```

i hope to help you